# Problema com date.timezone php.ini

Tags: php, ubuntu

Estou testando um bot do instagram na minha maquina local.
Mas quando tento iniciar modificar o `date.timezone` fica assim passando o parametro `date.timezone = America/Sao_Paulo` dentro do `php.ini`, que é uns dos requisitos para a aplicação poder ser instalada. Faço as alterações, salvo, mas ainda assim não permite que sejam instalando, mesmo atendendo os requisitos.

Uso UBUNTU 16.04 LTS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver esse problema é necessário verificar algumas configurações:

Siga até sua pasta home, que aponta para localhost e adicione esse script:

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
?>
```

Salve o arquivo como config.php em seguida execute em seu navegador.

> http://localhost/config.php

Verifique o path exato do seu php.ini, porque muitas instalações trazem vários samples de php.ini dentro dela e acidentalmente pode estar editando o arquivo erradamente.

[image: Load Configuration File]

Em seguida verifique o TimeZone conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: TimeZone]

Verifique se mudando também configurações no seu php.ini sofre as mudanças no seu config.php. Se não encontrar o problema retorne o feedback no seu post.